How to calculate page load in performance testing with page views for an hour and where to apply the load in jmeter scripts?
For each page, I have
Page views= 308,802 for an hour
Unique visitor = 211,778


The load is configured via Thread Group, there you can specify the number of users, iterations and test duration
308,802 views per hour is around 5147 requests per minute or 86 requests per second, you can use a suitable JMeter Timer for defining the desired throughput, for example:


Constant Throughput Timer


Precise Throughput Timer


Throughput Shaping Timer



Make sure to supply sufficient amount of threads (depends on the system under test response time)  as Timers can only pause the threads execution rate to limit it to the given throughput.
